# ArcGIS Explorer coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-explorer

I work with ArcGis Explorer and the coordinate system default is WGS 1984. Is it possible to change the coordinate system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.
The `Coordinates` window in the `Display` ribbon lets you choose common grids like D.d, DMS, UTM, as well as all other projected grids found in Esri platforms.
[image]

At second glance, it appears as though all these grids get an on-the-fly projection to fit the base system (probably a WGS84/Psuedo Mercator), so while basemap stays the same, the coordinates and the units change appropriately